# Asked to create form without using CSS. Get validation error

Tags: html

```
<table align="left" border="1" width="100%">
```

I set this in my code, why isnt it accepted? It looks great on the page but codewise

issue get this:

Error: The border attribute on the table element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.

From line 9, column 2; to line 9, column 45

ter↩   ↩       <ca

is the code incorrect or is it just asking for me to use css instead because html5 is old?

Am I using it correctly?